# Is there a way to run two apps being develped for android to run simultaneously from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I have developed two android apps (still in development stage though). One uses GPS and varies the time between two GPS locks. While the other is a battery app that logs the values. I want to install both on my device via eclipse. The problem is i can only do one at a time. Please help.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers for your questions

Answer (score 2):

You can just install them on your device and then run them not using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on a phone or emulator.
In emulator your apps will remain installed. Just do a solo run of the emulator and then check out the menu of the phone in the emulator you will be able to find both of your apps 
and remember to uncheck the option of WIPE USER DATA when you are creating an emulator

and If you want to test them in a phone then you need to export then using the export option and then generate APK's and then install in your phone and check them out .